# Why is the port not being mapped correctly?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, github-actions

I have a Github Action to run some tests in Python. Those tests need a postgressql service, so I create it and map the necessary port. To save time installing some dependencies, I use a docker container to run the action, with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y gdal-bin python2.7 python-pip git && \
    pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.1
EXPOSE 5432
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

And for the Github Action, I have the following workflow file:

```yaml
name: Run python tests

on: [push]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-16.04
    container:
      image: ghcr.io/myorg/python-unit-tests
      credentials:
        username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
        password: ${{ secrets.BOT_GITHUB_REGISTRY_TOKEN }}

    strategy:
      matrix:
        group: [1]

    services:
      postgres:
        image: cheewai/postgis:postgres-10.1
        env:
          PG_USER: postgres
          PG_PASSWORD: postgres
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
          POSTGRES_DB: test
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
        options: --health-cmd pg_isready --health-interval 10s --health-timeout 5s --health-retries 5

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          pip install -r requirements.txt
          pip install -r requirements_dev.txt

      - name: Prepare database
        run: |
          python manage.py migrate --noinput --settings=<somesettings>

      - name: Running tests (page ${{ matrix.group }})
        run: echo 'Run tests¡
```

With this configuration, it should be working nicely, but when I run it I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I added the `EXPOSE 5432` line because I thought it would fix it, but it does not work without it either. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: See the second part of my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64205417/3241243. It should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Could you post that as an answer? There's a way to change that behavior? I mean, continuing using localhost instead of the service name?

Comment: I would rather close yours as a duplicate. The only way to use `localhost` is by not running  your job in a container. As far as I know there's no other way and the docs don't mention anything either.