# Cannot connect to SQL Server with github action

Tags: c#, .net, docker, github-actions

I have been trying to figure this out since last Friday, I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database from my .net app. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
name: .NET
on:
  push:
    branches: [ CI567 ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ CI567 ]

jobs:
  container-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      sql.data:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
        env:
          SA_PASSWORD: WhatAmIDoing&Wrong
          ACCEPT_EULA: Y
        ports:
          - "1433:1433"
    steps:
    - name: list container images
      run: docker ps -a
    - name: checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 5.0.x
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
      working-directory: ./LabManager
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --no-restore
      working-directory: ./LabManager
    - name: Restore donettool
      run: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
      working-directory: ./LabManager
    - name: update database
      run: dotnet-ef database update --no-build
      working-directory: ./LabManager
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal
      working-directory: ./LabManager
```

Here's the connection string:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Test": "server=localhost,1433; User Id='SA'; Password='WhatAmIDoing&Wrong'"
  },
```

This is the error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
>
> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known

I have tried quoting the password with single and double. using docker run to create a SQL Server container. All resulted in this error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Service elasticsearch is not visible when run tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64204333/service-elasticsearch-is-not-visible-when-run-tests)

Comment: ill give this a try first thing at work. Thank you

Comment: @riQQ it is definitely a good read. but the problem still remains. :(

Answer (score 1):

Change the `server` to `Data Source` in the connection string

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Test": "Data Source=localhost,1433; User Id='SA'; Password='WhatAmIDoing&Wrong'"
  },
```

Comment: Thanks. i have tried this. but it worked after I changed the external port to 1401 from 1433. Dont know why tho

Comment: @HeChuan We are currently blocked by the same problem and can't find the solution. Would you mind sharing your working actions workflow and connection string as an answer? Thank you!

Comment: @MalteLatin hey there, original author here, what worked for me was changing the port number to something else. It was that stupid haha